# how to set interval by using widgets slider in mabplotlib

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, widget, slider, intervals

My data is like [0, 7, 14]

When writing the code
    xSlider = Slider(axesX, 'Slug pos X', 0, 14, 0)

When polling the slide, it will show floating value like 0, 0.3, 0.7....13.3, 14
I want to polling the slide value like 0, 7, 14

How should I do?

Comment: For a discrete slider also see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41152160/4124317)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you just want to convert the continuous range of the slider (0. to 14.) into three discrete values (0, 7, 14).  You can do this with the formula,

```
i = 7*int(round(x/7))
```

Which breaks the region into three sections, with the middle corresponding to `7` and the left and right quarters being `0` and `14`.

You could also just use something discrete like [`radio buttons`](http://matplotlib.org/examples/widgets/radio_buttons.html).