# Paging/scrolling through set of 2D heat maps in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I am generating 2D heat map plots of a set of 3D data. I would like to be able to have a mechanism to interactively page through each pane. Below is a simple sample code, I would like to be able to interactively view both panes (ie, z = [0,1]) via a slider bar (or some other means).  Is this possible with matplotlib or is this something I'll need to do post processing after generating the image files?

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
data = np.random.randint(10, size=(5, 5, 2))
data_slice = np.zeros((5,5))
for i in range(0, 5):
  for j in range(0, 5):
     data_slice[i][j] = data[i][j][0]
plt.imshow(data_slice, cmap='hot', interpolation='nearest')
plt.show()
```

Edit : I want to be able to do this *interactively* and it appears that the *[possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17835302/how-to-update-matplotlibs-imshow-window-interactively)* is trying to do this automatically.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to update matplotlib's imshow() window interactively?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17835302/how-to-update-matplotlibs-imshow-window-interactively)

Comment: No duplicate! This question asks about manually updating the matplotlib window, while the suggested question asks about doing that automatically. The solution is significantly different, because here a manual element (like a Slider in the answer) has to be used while in the automatic update a timer (FuncAnimation) needs to be used.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can either animate the layers as suggested by Andrew's comment or you can manually walk through the the layers using a slider as follow:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import Slider

# generate a five layer data 
data = np.random.randint(10, size=(5, 5, 5))
# current layer index start with the first layer 
idx = 0

# figure axis setup 
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
fig.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.15)

# display initial image 
im_h = ax.imshow(data[:, :, idx], cmap='hot', interpolation='nearest')

# setup a slider axis and the Slider
ax_depth = plt.axes([0.23, 0.02, 0.56, 0.04])
slider_depth = Slider(ax_depth, 'depth', 0, data.shape[2]-1, valinit=idx)

# update the figure with a change on the slider 
def update_depth(val):
    idx = int(round(slider_depth.val))
    im_h.set_data(data[:, :, idx])

slider_depth.on_changed(update_depth)

plt.show()
```

The slider is continues while the layer index is discrete integer, I hope that is not a problem. Here is the resulting figure,

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to control the value shown beside the slider, a part from using `valfmt`? In my case, that value represents an amount of minutes, but I would like to show something like "01:32" (i.e., a more readable time format) instead of "92".

Comment: You can redefine `matplotlib.widgets.Slider` - specifically the `set_val` method, as shown in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13656387/can-i-make-matplotlib-sliders-more-discrete. In order to format your time, you can use `datetime` from `datetime` module. `datetime.fromtimestamp(92).strftime("%M:%S")` => '01:32'

Answer (score 16):

The solution could indeed be to use a Slider as in the excellent answer by @hashmuke. In his answer he mentioned that 
*"The slider is continuous while the layer index is a discrete integer [...]"*

This brought me to think about a solution that wouldn't have this restriction and have
**a more page-like look and feel**.

The outcome is `PageSlider`. Subclassing  `Slider` it makes use of the slider functionality, but displays the slider in integer steps starting at `1`. It takes the number of pages `numpages` as init argument, but except of that works as `Slider` seen from the outside. Additionally it also provides a back- and forward button.

An example, similar to the one from  @hashmuke, is given below the class.

```
import matplotlib.widgets
import matplotlib.patches
import mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1

class PageSlider(matplotlib.widgets.Slider):

    def __init__(self, ax, label, numpages = 10, valinit=0, valfmt='%1d', 
                 closedmin=True, closedmax=True,  
                 dragging=True, **kwargs):

        self.facecolor=kwargs.get('facecolor',"w")
        self.activecolor = kwargs.pop('activecolor',"b")
        self.fontsize = kwargs.pop('fontsize', 10)
        self.numpages = numpages

        super(PageSlider, self).__init__(ax, label, 0, numpages, 
                            valinit=valinit, valfmt=valfmt, **kwargs)

        self.poly.set_visible(False)
        self.vline.set_visible(False)
        self.pageRects = []
        for i in range(numpages):
            facecolor = self.activecolor if i==valinit else self.facecolor
            r  = matplotlib.patches.Rectangle((float(i)/numpages, 0), 1./numpages, 1, 
                                transform=ax.transAxes, facecolor=facecolor)
            ax.add_artist(r)
            self.pageRects.append(r)
            ax.text(float(i)/numpages+0.5/numpages, 0.5, str(i+1),  
                    ha="center", va="center", transform=ax.transAxes,
                    fontsize=self.fontsize)
        self.valtext.set_visible(False)

        divider = mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1.make_axes_locatable(ax)
        bax = divider.append_axes("right", size="5%", pad=0.05)
        fax = divider.append_axes("right", size="5%", pad=0.05)
        self.button_back = matplotlib.widgets.Button(bax, label=ur'$\u25C0$', 
                        color=self.facecolor, hovercolor=self.activecolor)
        self.button_forward = matplotlib.widgets.Button(fax, label=ur'$\u25B6$', 
                        color=self.facecolor, hovercolor=self.activecolor)
        self.button_back.label.set_fontsize(self.fontsize)
        self.button_forward.label.set_fontsize(self.fontsize)
        self.button_back.on_clicked(self.backward)
        self.button_forward.on_clicked(self.forward)

    def _update(self, event):
        super(PageSlider, self)._update(event)
        i = int(self.val)
        if i >=self.valmax:
            return
        self._colorize(i)

    def _colorize(self, i):
        for j in range(self.numpages):
            self.pageRects[j].set_facecolor(self.facecolor)
        self.pageRects[i].set_facecolor(self.activecolor)

    def forward(self, event):
        current_i = int(self.val)
        i = current_i+1
        if (i < self.valmin) or (i >= self.valmax):
            return
        self.set_val(i)
        self._colorize(i)

    def backward(self, event):
        current_i = int(self.val)
        i = current_i-1
        if (i < self.valmin) or (i >= self.valmax):
            return
        self.set_val(i)
        self._colorize(i)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import numpy as np
    from matplotlib import pyplot as plt


    num_pages = 23
    data = np.random.rand(9, 9, num_pages)

    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    fig.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.18)

    im = ax.imshow(data[:, :, 0], cmap='viridis', interpolation='nearest')

    ax_slider = fig.add_axes([0.1, 0.05, 0.8, 0.04])
    slider = PageSlider(ax_slider, 'Page', num_pages, activecolor="orange")

    def update(val):
        i = int(slider.val)
        im.set_data(data[:,:,i])

    slider.on_changed(update)

    plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: The  label=ur'$\u25C0$' needs to remove "r"  to be label=u'$\u25C0$'.
The  label=ur'$\u25B6$' needs to remove "r"  to be label=u'$\u25B6$'.