# Is it possible to switch between which plot to display using the built in arrows?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to create a "program" that allows me to have 2 seperate plots, in 1 window. I don't want them to be displayed at the same time, I want to be able to switch between the plots using the arrows at the bottom of the figure window.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import matplotlib.style as style
import plotgen

style.use("bmh")
dp = 30

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1, label="ax1")
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1, label="ax2")


cax = 2

plotgen.clear("plot1.txt")
plotgen.clear("plot2.txt")

def animate(i):
    if cax == 1:
        plotgen.generate("plot1.txt")
        graph_data = open('plot1.txt', 'r').read()
        lines = graph_data.split('\n')
        xs = []
        ys = []
        for line in lines:
            if len(line) > 1:
                x, y = line.split(',')
                xs.append(x)
                ys.append(float(y))
        ax1.clear()
        pxs = 0
        pys = 0
        lx = len(xs)
        ly = len(ys)
        if len(xs) < dp:
            pxs = xs
            pys = ys
        else:
            pxs = xs[(lx - (dp - 1)):(lx - 1)]
            pys = ys[(ly - (dp - 1)):(ly - 1)]
        ax1.plot(pxs, pys, "r")
    elif cax == 2:
        plotgen.generate("plot2.txt")
        graph_data = open('plot2.txt', 'r').read()
        lines = graph_data.split('\n')
        xs = []
        ys = []
        for line in lines:
            if len(line) > 1:
                x, y = line.split(',')
                xs.append(x)
                ys.append(float(y))
        ax2.clear()
        pxs = 0
        pys = 0
        lx = len(xs)
        ly = len(ys)
        if len(xs) < dp:
            pxs = xs
            pys = ys
        else:
            pxs = xs[(lx - (dp - 1)):(lx - 1)]
            pys = ys[(ly - (dp - 1)):(ly - 1)]
        ax2.plot(pxs, pys)

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, interval=500)
plt.show()
```

At the moment I am currently switching between what plot I want to see on the figure using the `cax` variable, this is the one I want to increase or decrease using the arrows.

Also for some reason I can't see the `ax1` subplot, I think it's "behind" `ax2`. The data generating works for both though.

I just wanted to clarify what I wanted the answer for:

1: "Is it possible to use the arrows to switch between plots?"

2: "Is it possible to make one plot invisible when it's plotting the other (remove x and y axis aswell so they don't mix)"

3: "Why can't I see `ax1`?"

Comment: (1) Possible, but very hard. (2) `ax.set_visible(False)` would make `ax` invisible. (3) You cannot see  `ax1`, because `ax2` is on top of it.

Comment: Thanks, is there an event happening when I click it? If so I can just use something like `fig.canvas.mpl_connect('next_arrow_event', next)`

Comment: It's not that simple. What about adding your own buttons, like in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44985966/managing-dynamic-plotting-in-matplotlib-animation-module) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41152160/4124317)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue I had with `ax1` not showing by using `ax2.set_visible(False)`. And when I changed the plots I made it visible again and made ax1 invisible.

I also added buttons to my plot using this short piece of code:

```py
axnext = plt.axes([0.80, 0.01, 0.06, 0.06])
axprev = plt.axes([0.73, 0.01, 0.06, 0.06])

bnext = Button(axnext, 'Next >')
bnext.on_clicked(self.changePlotNext)
bprev = Button(axprev, "< Previous")
bprev.on_clicked(self.changePlotPrev)
```

Then I just added simple functions that would increase or decrease the `cax` variable I have. I had to do some minor edits to my animate function to save resources when plotting, and I also deleted the second subplot and decided to just have one instead.