# plot multiple figures in the same window but different "tabs" with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I know that you can plot multiple figures in the same window by arranging them in a grid layout. However, I want to plot multiple figures, showing only one at a time and be able to move to the next or previous figure with buttons in the UI. I see arrows in the default UI which makes me think there's a way to do this.

Comment: Take a look at https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/widgets/buttons.html

Comment: The arrow buttons are used to go back and forth between different states of the same figure, e.g. to return to the previous view after zooming. They will not help for changing the figure content. Possibly you want something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41143782/paging-scrolling-through-set-of-2d-heat-maps-in-matplotlib/41152160#41152160)?